# Enlarge font with iterm2 and tmux

Tags: applescript, iterm

I've tried just about everything to figure out a way to automatically bump up the font size much larger when I hit a hot key in tmux by triggering a script. Only thing I got working is this which is very hacky and slow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

osascript -e '
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "++++++++++++++++++++" using command down
'
```

This works but only with shell integration:

`echo -e "\033]50;SetProfile=Development_Large\a"`

But the problem is shell integration does not work with tmux.

Anything else I can do? I've tried applescript to change the current profile but I could not get any of them to work. Example:

```
osascript -e "
tell application \"iTerm2\"
  tell current window
    tell current tab
      set profile to \"cheat\"
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
"
```

This script just outputs "cheat" to the terminal.

Is there something else I might try?

Comment: This works: create tab with profile "Development_Large"

But I want to *change* the profile of the current tab.

Comment: RE: "This works: create tab with profile "Development_Large" --  Yes, because `with profile` is a part of the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ of **ITerm2**, its a _property_. `profile` as in `set profile to ...` is **not** a part of the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ of **ITerm2**, and in its context it is nothing more than a _variable_ to which `cheat` was assigned. -- RE: "But I want to change the profile of the current tab" --  Looking at the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ of **ITerm2**,  I do not see a mechanism by which to do that with **AppleScript**.

Comment: I just found a solution. Will post.

Answer (score 1):

I hit upon a solution:

**Step 1:** In iterm, open the preferences panel for the profile you will be switching *from*

**Step 2:** Click on the "Keys" tab for the profile

**Step 3:** Add a new key mapping by clicking on the plus sign.

**Step 4:** Choose the "keyboard shortcut" as desired and under "action", select "change profile". Now select the profile you want to switch to. Click "OK"

**Step 5:** Use something like the following bash script to trigger the key mapping:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "z" using {command down,control down}'`

You will need to modify this script to use your chosen hotkey.

One other very useful but somewhat unrelated tip for modifying fonts is to give tmux the "resize-window" command to fix the window size. This prevents the panes from resizing when switching font sizes.

Comment: Because this is part of a command used with a tmux hotkey: bind E resize-pane -Z \; run-shell "bash -c ~/bin/profile.sh"

Comment: The above key bind for tmux will zoom the pane to take up the whole screen and resize the font. And I have another keybind to zoom out.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `resize-window` comment? I want iTerm2 to stop resizing the window when increasing font size in tmux. It doesn't resize the window for my default profile.

Comment: I don't recall the details but I've got this in my tmux config file: `bind E resize-pane -Z \; run-shell "bash -c ~/bin/profile.sh; sleep 0.3" \; resize-window -A`